UI freezes on tap of an item inside ScrollView: "Gesture: System gesture gate timed out."
I'm trying to implement a feed of flash cards using SwiftUI.
So I create a ScrollView and populate flash cards inside this ScrollView.
My intention is to be able to go to the next card by vertical swipe, and flip the card by tapping it.
So I created my VisualFeedView which contains the ScrollView and inside of this ScrollView I populate my cards.
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct VisualFeedView: View {
    
    @State private var showingAudioFeed = false
    @StateObject private var viewModel = VisualFeedViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.gliteBackground().ignoresSafeArea()
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack(spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(viewModel.currentCards) { card in
                        TwoSidedCardView(content: card)
                            .containerRelativeFrame([.horizontal, .vertical])
                    }
                }
            }
            .scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            .scrollIndicators(.never)
            .onAppear() {
                viewModel.refreshFeed()
            }
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Button {
                        showingAudioFeed.toggle()
                    } label: {
                        ZStack {
                            Circle()
                                .fill(Color(.sRGB, white: 0, opacity: 0.6))
                                .frame(width: 52, height: 52)
                            Image("HeadphonesLargeIcon")
                        }
                        
                    }
                    .sheet(isPresented: $showingAudioFeed) {
                        AudioFeedView()
                    }
                    .padding(.trailing, 24.0)
                }
                .padding(.top)
            Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct VisualFeedView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        VisualFeedView()
    }
}

My FlashCard view is the following:
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

enum TwoSidedCardViewState {
    case front
    case back
}

struct TwoSidedCardView: View {
    var content: TwoSidedCardContent
    @State private var frontSide = true

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if frontSide {
                CardFrontSideView(content: content)
            } else {
                CardBackSideView(content: content)
            }
        }
        .clipped()
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation {
                frontSide.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TwoSidedCardView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    
    static var previews: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.gliteBackground().ignoresSafeArea()
        }
    }
}

What do I do wrong?
Sometimes when I tap on the card the whole UI just freezes.
Sometimes when I scroll it - it works well, but when I tap any card it freezes as well.
Sometimes I receive this message in the console " Gesture: System gesture gate timed out."
What's happening and how can I debug this simple functionality?

trying removing the if from the row content, that really slows it down. Also try removing the view model object and using View structs as the view model as designed. It's fine to use a state object as an async fetcher but not to hold view data (fyi .task has made StateObject redundant).
